# Can AutoFixture not read [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(10)")]

Tags: autofixture

I have a EF model with a property like this

```
[Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(20)")]
public string DistrictName { get; set; }
```

I am using AutoFixture to generate some test data but when I save it gets an error:

```
String or binary data would be truncated in table 'EFTestSample.Activity.Addresses', column 'DistrictName'. Truncated value: 'DistrictName42b0b45f'.
```

Can AutoFixture not read the attribute and respect this restriction ? I know I can tell it explicitly but I have quite a few of these and it would be great not to do for each one of them

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the most elegant solution but you can try to add MaxLength to the model. AutoFixture will respect it:

```
[Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(20)")]
[MaxLength(20)]
public string DistrictName { get; set; }
```

Teaching AutoFixture to respect the existing `Column` attribute sounds like a new feature request. One will need to implement something similar to the [MinAndMaxLengthAttributeRelay](https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture/blob/77de7c2a4367013a27a17c4929a472a02f8f0465/Src/AutoFixture/DataAnnotations/MinAndMaxLengthAttributeRelay.cs#L11) class.